# checkbox logic not working in open layers js file

Tags: javascript, html, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

In my code i have two grid on for base layer other for utility layer .
Base layer has radio button  and on clicking the logic used is working

```
{

    var baseLayerGroup= new ol.layer.Group({
    layers:[
        openstreetmapstandard,openstreetmaphumanitarian
    ]
})
map.addLayer(baseLayerGroup);

//Layer Switcher Logic for Baselayer
var baseLayerElements = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar1 > input[type=radio]');
for(let baseLayerElement of baseLayerElements){
    baseLayerElement.addEventListener('change',function(){
        let baseLayerElementValue = this.value;
        baseLayerGroup.getLayers().forEach(function(element, index, array){
            let baseLayerTitle = element.get('title');
            element.setVisible(baseLayerTitle === baseLayerElementValue);        
        })
    })
}
var dataLayerGroup= new ol.layer.Group({
    layers:[
        Sector_office,Roads
    ]
})
```

and my logic for checkbox is :

```
Sector_office.setVisible(true);
Roads.setVisible(false);
var toggleLayer = function(inputEl){
     map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
          if (layer.get('name') === inputEl.name)
          layer.setVisible(inputEl.checked);
          });
        };
map.addLayer(dataLayerGroup);
```

but my checkbox logic is not working  and here is my html page for it

```
   <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLayer(this);" value="Sector_office" checked>Sector office<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLayer(this);" value="Roads" checked>Roads<br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I see you have a couple of issues in your code.

In the handler function you are referencing the `name` attribute of the dom element, but I see not such attribute in the html. That will always result `false`. So you have to set the `name` attribute or use the `value` attribute.

The `onclick` event handler receive as a parameter a `MouseEvent` argument. To get a reference of the dom element inside the handler you can use `this` or you can use the event argument attribute `target`.

Resuming,

*handler*

```js
const toggleLayer = function(e){
    const chk = e.target.
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
        if (layer.get('name') === chk.value)
        layer.setVisible(chk.checked);
    });
};
```

*html*

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer(event)"
    value="Sector_office" checked>Sector office<br> 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleLayer(event)"
    value="Roads" checked>Roads<br>
```